# Counting number of $2\times 2$ unimodular matrices of particular type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, rational-points, modular-group

From set of numbers from $\Bbb S=\{0,1,\dots,m\}$, how many distinct $3\times 3$ unimodular matrices parametrized by $(a,b,c,d,e,f)\in\Bbb S^6$ of following type can one form?
\begin{bmatrix}
a^2 &ab &b^2\\
c^2 &cd &d^2\\
e^2 &ef &f^2\\
\end{bmatrix}

Is it at least $3m^{2+\beta}$ for some $\beta>0$ when $m\gg0$?

From comment below determinant is $$(ad-bc)(af-be)(cd-ef).$$

So how many $3$ tuples of $2\times 2$ matrices of following type with determinant being simultaneously $\pm1$ with entries from $\Bbb S$?
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a &c\\
b &d
\end{bmatrix}\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
c &e\\
d &f
\end{bmatrix}\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
e &a\\
f &b
\end{bmatrix}$$

An example matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1 &1\\
9 &6 &4\\
4 &2 &1\\
\end{bmatrix} has determinant $-1$.

**Update:**

As determined below by Kantelope and Neil Strickland, rough asymptotics seem to be at least $3m^2$. Could this be improved to $3m^{2+\beta}$ for some $\beta>0$ when $m\gg0$?

Comment: The determinant is $(ad-bc)(af-be)(cf-de)$.

Comment: Take $(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(1,0,x+1,1,x,1)$. This only gives you $\approx m$ solutions though. Also $(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(1,1,x,x+1,x+1,x+2)$, etc.

Comment: Please post as answer. There should be a way to get more. That gives you $m+1$ solutions each. What does 'etc' mean? There should be a convenient bivariate parametrization yielding $\Theta(m^2)$ such $3\times 3$ determinant $\pm1$ transformations.

Comment: Is there a way to count all?

Comment: Similarly $(2,1,2x+1,x,2y+1,y)$, with $y(2x+1)=x(2y+1)\pm 1$, so $x=y\pm 1$. This should generalize to any $(a,1)$ pair. So $(a,1,ax+1,x,ay+1,y)$ for any $x=y\pm 1$, though you have to be careful counting $|ax|\le m$.

Comment: This does not give $\approx m^2$ solutions since $y$ and $x$ are related.

Comment: I am sorry but every time I read a question posed by this user, I have a feeling that we are writing up their thesis or at any rate, their paper.

Comment: @knsam what thesis? I am been posting fairly straight forward counting problems and looking for technology behind them.

Comment: I was only guessing but none of the questions indicate any work from your side.

Comment: @knsam probably that means that number theory is not my main cup of tea and am looking for some insights to get to the right framework and questions.

Answer (score 1):

I will first refine kantelope's analysis slightly.

We want $(ad-bc)(af-be)(cf-de)=1$, so the three factors must be $\pm 1$.  For the moment I will consider the case where $(ad-bc)=(af-be)=(cf-de)=1$.  This means that $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Let $(u,v)$ be the smallest pair of strictly positive integers such that $av-bu=1$.  Any other such pair must then have the form $(u+ia,v+ib)$ for some $i\geq 0$.  Thus, there must be integers $i,j\geq 0$ such that $(c,d)=(u+ia,v+ib)$ and $(e,f)=(u+ja,v+jb)$.  This gives 
$$cf-de=(u+ia)(v+jb)-(v+ib)(u+ja)=(i-j)(av-bu)=i-j,$$
so we need $i=j+1$.  Thus, the number of solutions starting with $(a,b)$ is the number of $j\geq 0$ such that $u+(j+1)a\leq m$ and also $v+(j+1)b\leq m$.  This makes it easy to write code to calculate the number $G(m)$ of solutions for any given $m$.  It appears from the numerics that $G(m)/m^2$ converges to a limit which is about $0.6$.  However, I have only calculated as far as $m=1000$, which is not far enough to see whether there might be logarithmic corrections.

Comment: Would it be $2^3\times 0.6=4.8$ if you include $\pm1$ sign?

Comment: @Arul: I think that it is more complicated than that, but I do not have a complete analysis.  The function is invariant under a group of order $6$ generated by $(a,b,c,d,e,f)\mapsto (c,d,e,f,a,b)$ and $(a,b,c,d,e,f)\mapsto (d,c,b,a,f,e)$.

Comment: do you have any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

For any given $(a,b)$, find $(c,d)$ with $ad-bc=1$ (Euclid), and note $(a,b,c,d,a+c,b+d)$ is a solution. You still have to worry about whether $a+c$ or $b+d$ is too large, but if $a,b\le m/2$ everything should be OK.

Comment: Following Bézout, the extended GCD algorithm gives you $c,d$ with $|d|\lt |a|$ and $|c|\lt |b|$. This follows straight from quotient-remainder. That's why I said it's OK if $a,b\le m/2$ (and $a,b$ should be coprime of course). Then $c,d\le m/2$ also, and their sums are $\le m$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: oh I see this does seem to give $\Theta(m^2)$ distinct matrices. Can this be improved to $\Theta(m^3)$ or is this the best?

Comment: The variety $ad-bc=af-be=cf-de=1$ (or any of the $2^3$ related $\pm$ varieties) should be dimension 3. However, you want integral solutions (not rational), so I'd expect $m^2$ is the right rough order of magnitude, though likely times some log-power -- compare: the number of integral $ad-bc=1$ solutions (again a dim 3 variety) up to height $m$ should be like $\sum_{a,b\le m}(m/a)(m/b)\approx (m\log m)^2$.

Comment: Oops, maybe that last bit should be $\sum_{a,b\le m} m/\max(a,b)\approx 2\sum_{a\le b\le m} m/b\approx 2m^2$ (and multiply by $6/\pi^2$ for coprimality, though I've been ignoring any constants throughout, and again taking $a,b\le m/2$ might be easier to analyze), so I don't know if there are logs or not.

Comment: Could you elaborate the algebraic geometric picture more clearly in your posting? Also some references. I could take a look and get back. How does dimension relate to integer or rational point count?